# C# How can I call an http post method and get back the results

Tags: c#, restsharp

I have a method that is a http Post I call that method and pass along 2 parameter then it returns 2 parameters back . I have it working the traditional way but now I would like to get it working using RestSharp .I would like to call that method now using RestSharp but I am having no luck .  This below works

```
    public static void Main() {
        var getController = new AccessController();
        var merchSales = getController.Merchandise("Bags",5);

        var status = merchSales.Status;
        var items = merchSales.ItemsCount; 
        if (status.sold == status)
         {
           console("It's Sold");
         }
          else if (status.available == status)
         {
            console("It's Available");
         }

         }
```

I am now trying to do that using RestSharp http://restsharp.org/ . However How can I get back the return value of the Enum to do an If statement check like I did above ?  For instance in the code above the **merchSales.Status** is an enum that will return either **Available** or **Sold** . This is my code below it's meant to be a HTTP call

```
     public static void Main() {
       var client = new RestClient ("http://localhost:1275/api/");
       var request = new RestRequest("Resource/{id}", Method.POST);
       request.AddParameter("Item", "Bags");
        request.AddParameter("Count", 5);

       RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
   client.ExecuteAsync(request, data => {
                    Console.WriteLine(data.Content);
                });


             }
```

Comment: Currently what value you are getting in `response` variable and `data.Content`?

Comment: Can you add the header (Request Body Type) and then check? Please share the input content type?